# In sqlalchemy, what corresponds to the mysql function 'load_file'?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am tempting to insert a .npz file into a mysql column using the mysql function ['LOAD_FILE'](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) (seems this should work), but I can't find any correspondence in sqlalchemy's ORM layer, and neither can I afford to write the mysql query in a lower layer. Does anybody know the solution? Thanks :)

Comment: In the future please include your models and any code you've produced in an attempt to solve the issue at hand. Read about [mcve]. Without you risk having your question closed, getting down voted, and receiving a lot of answers that don't quite answer your question.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä Thank you for your informing... I'll take care in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

You do have to write the function expression in a lower layer, mainly in [SQL Expression Language](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html), or in other words use the [generic functions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html):

```
func.load_file('/path/to/my/file.npz')
```

given that the file exists on your DB server and other conditions are met. So for an imaginary `Something` model you'd simply [pass the function expression as the value](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/persistence_techniques.html#embedding-sql-insert-update-expressions-into-a-flush) when creating an instance:

```
some = Something(some_blob=func.load_file('/path/to/my/file.npz'))
session.add(some)
session.commit()
```

[Core](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/) and the [ORM](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html) are meant to work together, such as in this case.

Comment: Wow that's great man! I haven't payed enough attention to this layer before...  A big thanks!